# Given a specific Lat/Lon, determine the angle required to create 10m spacing of pixels

Tags: gdal

I have a ge3otiff in WGS84 format, with Pixel Size = (0.000011335151125,-0.000011335151125).
which is approximately 1m / pixel. I want to down sample this GeoTIFF to 10m resolution, but still needs file to be in WGS84 and pixel sized in degrees.

How do I figure out what is the appropriate pixel size in deg. for a resolution of 10m?

Web search for Meters to deg for given coordinates, I see nothing which I can use.

Answer (score 1):

For a Geographic Coordinate System with a fixed angular spacing across pixels, the distance across a pixel in the vertical (latitude) direction is roughly the angle in radians times the radius of the Earth.  For example

Dist = (Delta_Lat * PI/180)*6378137    (in meters)

This calculation assumes a spherical Earth, which is probably close enough for many applications. So in your case, you just need

Delta_Lat = (Dist/6378137)*(180/PI)

This calculation is complicated somewhat in the horizontal (x-axis) direction because of the convergence of the meridians (lines of longitude get closer together as you move away from the equator). It will change for each row of pixels, but if you look at the center latitude for your image, you would have:

Dist = Cosine(Center_Latitude)*(Delta_Lon * PI/180)*6378137

Finally, this is probably more detail than you need, but there is a discussion of computing pixel scale for GeoTIFFs with a Geographic Coordinate System at the web article [Elevation GeoTIFFs and Shaded Relief](https://gwlucastrig.github.io/GridfourDocs/notes/ElevationGeoTiff1.html)